# How to deploy a python webapp with dependencies using virtualenv?

Tags: python, virtualenv

I'm looking for a way to automate deployment of web applications written in Python to a server. I would like to use *virtualenv* to have a clean environment for this application.

However, **I am wondering how to manage dependencies when deploying to the server ?**

In development, I have a *virtualenv* in which I install external libraries using *pip*, so I am looking for a way to automatically install those dependencies in production ?

Thank you for your time

Comment: Can you rename the question to include `python` and `virtualenv` to it, please. Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

With pip you can create a requirements file:

```
$ pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

Then in the server to install all of these you do:

```
$ pip install -r requirements.txt
```

And with this (if the server has everything necessary to build the binary packages that you might have included) all is ready.

Comment: so you don't use virtualenv on the server? So if your host multiple sites they all get the module soup that is all their shared environments and if you upgrade a module of one you have to test them all...?