# Is it wrong to package Python with my framework?

Tags: python, frameworks, distribution, bundle

Here's the deal. I am developing a framework whose sole users have extremely messed up python installations on their servers (Linux). They all have multiple versions of Python on their servers and their PYTHONHOME and PYTHONPATH variables are pointing to different versions.

Since my framework will require Python 2.6, I thought that a safe way to distribute my application might be to bundle a pre-compiled version of Python with my application. To test this theory out, I downloaded ActivePython and bundled all the necessary files with by application. My main script calls #!/vendor/ActivePython2.6/bin/python.

So far, I have tested the framework on different server distributions and with different people's servers and it seems to have worked so far with no problems (yet).

My question is, are there any problems in doing this and are there any alternatives?

Comment: (I believe there are programs that will do all this bundling "for you"; if so, chances are they will have more of the potential issues worked out ;-)

Comment: @pst - would you happen to be talking about distutils, setuptools, etc? I've looked at those, however, I couldn't find anything about managing python version dependencies.

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend against it. You'll run into problems between 32b and 64b versions, between different libc versions, noexec locations, wrong selinux/apparmor profiles for custom paths and many other potential problems...

Unless you're planning to release (and test!) a package for each separate distribution, architecture and version, I'd say you're creating problems for yourself. The alternative is to provide both versions of course - provide the framework only by default and make the static python package available in case of problems.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Are there any guides or how-tos that mention how to deal with python dependencies when distributing an application?

Comment: `virtualenv` and `pip freeze / install` are pretty much the standard - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3211080/how-to-deploy-a-python-webapp-with-dependencies-using-virtualenv